# Escape analysis const vs var

Tags: go, compiler-optimization

I am currently looking at escape analysis example from [David Chenys HighPerformanceGo](https://dave.cheney.net/high-performance-go-workshop/gophercon-2019.html#escape_analysis), from the second code block the author is demonstrating when a variable does not escape to the heap even if it's a reference type, the code block demonstrated in the blog post for the second example is thus

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func Sum() int {
    var count = 100
    numbers := make([]int, count)
    for i := range numbers {
        numbers[i] = i + 1
    }

    var sum int
    for _, i := range numbers {
        sum += i
    }
    return sum
}

func main() {
    answer := Sum()
    fmt.Println(answer)
}
```

Building the code with `go build allocate.go -gcflags="-m"` shows that `numbers` escapes to the heap which is analogous to what the author described (but this is not a concern for me).

```golang
./stack.go:9:17: make([]int, count) escapes to heap
./stack.go:22:15: make([]int, count) escapes to heap
```

Updating the definition of count to a constant `const count = 100` and rebuilding the code with `go build allocate.go -gcflags="-m"` shows that numbers does not escape to the heap.

```golang
./stack.go:9:17: make([]int, count) does not escape
./stack.go:22:15: make([]int, count) does not escape
```

The first thought that came into my mind was that "the reason for this difference is because the size of numbers is known at compile time"

But updating `count` to a higher value ( `const count = 10000` ) causes `numbers` to escape to the heap. I understand that `10000` is too big to be allocated on the stack, hence it escapes to the heap, but my concern is why does `const count = 100` not behave in the same way as `var count = 100` when it relates to using their values with `make([]int, count)`

Is there any subtle difference that exists between `const` and `var` and how it affects `make([]int, count)` ?

Comment: "Is there any subtle difference that exists between const and var and how it affects make([]int, count) ?" No, these are implementation details and might change in the next version of the compiler.